# Having trouble displaying adjacent cell's values on a different sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This code is giving me trouble. I wanted to scan for a keyword in column B, and displays the value of the cell next to it (so it would be column A same row) in a separate worksheet. I have written the code, and highlighted the troubled part. It only displays the final value and not the rest of the values. I would appreciate any help.

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim rcell As Range
Dim Sum_Payment As Double
Dim Dates_Array() As Double
Dim Cash_Array()  As Double
Dim i As Integer



Set MyRange = Worksheets("Database").Range("B2:B50")

    For Each rcell In MyRange.Cells
            If rcell.Value = "Payment" Then
                ***For i = 1 To 30***
                    Sum_Payment = Sum_Payment + rcell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    ***Dates_Array(i) = rcell.Offset(i, -1).Value
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A10:A20") = Dates_Array(i)***
                Next i

        End If
    Next rcell
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2") = Sum_Payment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the same range every time you go through the loop. If I understand your description correctly, this line...

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A10:A20") = Dates_Array(i)
```

...should be:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rcell.Row, 1) = Dates_Array(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and I changed it to your suggestion, but "Dates_Array(i) = rcell.Offset(i, -1).Value " gives me an error (subscript out of range).. I may have to ReDim the array, and I'm trying to figure out how ReDim works.

Comment: @Lonewolf - I'd presumed that was in the omitted code. Now that I'm looking at your loop, you shouldn't need the array at all.  Just set `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rcell.Row, 1) = rcell.Offset(i, -1).Value` and remove all the array references.  If this isn't what you're intending to do, then I apparently ***don't*** understand your description correctly.

Comment: It did not work as intended, Thanks for you help tho.

Comment: @Lonewolf - What exactly ***is*** intended? Can you edit your post to add the expected input and output?

Comment: Update - it works now. Thanks again. To summarize: I have a transaction sheet. The program goes through one column and finds a specific keyword (e,g cash) it is then going to copy the value of the cell besides cash and paste it in another worksheet.